# Autoprefixer in ANT build

Tags: ant, bootstrap-4, autoprefixer

I am planning to use Bootstrap 4 and customise the theme. They recommend sass and Autoprefixer. I don't have node or maven. We use Ant for the build. To compile sass, Ruby plug in is available for Ant. I don't see any option to use Autoprefixer in Ant. Please help

Comment: You should move to a newer build tool that's more frontend oriented - possibly `grunt` or `gulp`. That'll help you in the long run as well. Right now, you could move just the autoprefixer task to gulp, and invoke gulp from ant via [exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use autoprefixer-cli which can be accessed through ANT using 'exec' tag. To use autoprefixer, you can install it using gulp and use the files generated through it. I did the same thing and it worked.